# Using an object/curve as a stencil or mask of sorts for texture paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm currently trying to retexture a Spider-Man model I made, and the webbing on his suit are proving to be difficult. I modeled them first, and have been trying to use different methods of baking for them, none of which have really come out great. So now, I'm resorting to trying out texture paint, and simply tracing the webs isn't quite working out all that well. So I'm curious, is there any way I could use his 3D modeled webs as a mask of sorts while texture painting onto the suit model? Like, a way I could be in texture paint mode on the suit model, and if my brush went over a part of the webbing's model, it wouldn't paint onto the suit. Sorry if I didn't explain that quite right, thanks in advance!
[image: The model in its current state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bake an ambient occlusion pass to a texture that would give you black where the web intersects or touches the suit mesh.